# Positioning of background image at specific position

Tags: html, css

I have a slider which contains previous,next and pause button.These buttons are displayed at the bottom side of the image slider which i want to be displayed at the center of the image slider but its not happening.

Here is the css of the one of the background image.

```
.skdslider a.prev{
background: url("image/left.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
width:35px;
height:35px;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:2%;
margin-top:-17px;
```

}

How to move the position of this image to the center ,i mean to upper side of the page.
Please help me .

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to position the background-image within the image frame itself. To do so, use `background-position` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

I think you're looking for this:`background-position:center center;`

Comment: will u able to add fiddle im not clear abt the question

Answer (score 0):

Add background as below.

> background: url("image/left.png") no-repeat center;

Comment: Your problem is different then. As per my understanding, you have slider with images and controls at bottom which has to be move at center of slider. If you do so, controls will get hide below slider. You cannot add background image over a markup element. Add img tag and give it a z-index.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
background-image:url('./you/url.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
```